# Why "npm start" command does not run the TypeScript app after successful build

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, package.json

I want debug a TypeScript/Node app in VS Code by putting some breakpoints in the code. So I followed [this instruction](https://medium.com/@PhilippKief/how-to-debug-typescript-with-vs-code-9cec93b4ae56). But I have a problem.

I set the `packages.json` scripts, but when I use `npm start` it does not run the app.

[image]

`npm start` does:

- Building (compile) the project to the `out` folder (I can see the new `bot1.js` and other related files and folders in this path: `/out/bot1`)
- Show the following messages

  ```
   [4:00:05 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

   [4:00:09 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
  ```
- But does not run the app after compilation

On the other hand if I run `node out/bot1/bot1.js` in the terminal manually it starts the app successfully.

Also I have same problem when I run the program by Debug start button (F5) in VS Code.

`launch.json`:

[image]

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./out",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

What do you think? What is the problem?

Comment: *"Starting compilation in watch mode"* - `npm run build` starts in watch mode (due to `"watch": true,`), so the `prestart` command (or `preLaunchTask`) never finishes and the `start` command (or `launch`) never starts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Why `prestart` command -`npm run build`- never finishes while it make the out folder and files and show `Found 0 errors`? How should I solve it?

Comment: Because *you told it to watch*. It builds the current code, then sits and watches for any changes so it can rebuild; it **can't** finish. You should solve it by *not* telling it to watch (or building and running simultaneously, with both watching, like I have done [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/68bbda5f72dc052b8731404d6470c4e3877389f7/package.json#L13-L16)).

Comment: Wow! @jonrsharpe, your answer was exactly correct and solved my problem. Please write it as an answer here.